# call a function if popup is not answered

Tags: javascript, jquery

The scenario is : After every hour users will get a popup (javascript/jQuery). If the user does not respond to the pop up the session gets destroyed. Now I am facing a problem about how to fire a function if the pop up is not answered. Please help.As far my code is as below.

```
function popitup() {
newwindow=window.open('/Untitled-3.html','name','height=500,width=500');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
//popitup();
function showpop(){
var x;
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r==true)
{
x="You pressed OK!";

}
else
{
x="You pressed Cancel!";
closeWin();
}
setTimeout(closeWin,15000);
}
function closeWin()
{
newwindow.close();                                               
}
setInterval ( showpop, 10000 );
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what answered means??

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp Maybe with a confirm?

Comment: When the popup is shown, start a timer (say a few minutes). If the user responds, cancel the timer, else have the timer destroy the session.

Answer (score 0):

Use **setTimeout** in in your `popitup` function like this

```
function popitup() {
setTimeout(closeWin,60000);// here I've taken 60 seconds as the response time to call closeWin function
    newwindow = window.open('/abc.html', 'name', 'height=500,width=500');
    if (window.focus) {
        newwindow.focus()
    }
    return false;
}
```

After 60 seconds of your popup is opened, closeWin function will be called,you can call any function like this.

[ref](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

**Update:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
      var myVar;
      function popitup() {
          newwindow = window.open('Default.aspx', 'name', 'height=500,width=500');
          if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
          myVar = setInterval(showpop, 10000);
          return false;
      }
      //popitup(); 
      function showpop() {
          var x;
          //debugger;
          var counter = setTimeout(closeWin, 5000);
          $(function () {
              $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                  resizable: false,
                  height: 140,
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                      Ok: function () {
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                          clearTimeout(counter);
                      },
                      Cancel: function () {
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                          closeWin();
                          clearInterval(myVar);
                      }
                  }
              });
          });


          //setTimeout(function(){closeWin()},15000); 
      }
      function closeWin() {
          //debugger; 
          newwindow.close();
      }

  </script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="do you wan to continue?">
    </div>
<a href="#" onclick="popitup()">blah</a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply but nothing happened with your code. What i want to do is after x seconds of the appearance of the pop up if you don't click 'ok'  you will be logged out from the site.

Comment: then why don't you try a `window.confirm()` [reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) and setTimeout() to call a function after that time period has expired.

Comment: setTimeout(closeWin,60000); when placed inside the function showpop(), it is not closing off anything.Plz help.

Comment: try the updated code and place a debuuger in closeWin function to check wheteher funtion calling is done properly or not, like this

`function closeWin()
{
debugger;
newwindow.close();                                               
}`

Comment: if the pop is not clicked at all, in that default case I need the setTimeout.

Comment: neither in the console nor in the debugger it is throwing anything. Phew.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46226/discussion-between-sid-m-and-aritra)

Answer (score 0):

Instead `setInterval` try `setTimeOut(closeWin, 10000);`
This will call closeWin function after 10 seconds.

[setTimeOut ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Alternativey you can try something like this:

`res = confirm("You Message here"); if(res==true) {window.location="abc.html"}`

`setTimeout(function(){window.location="abc.html"},10000);`

Comment: setTimeout(closeWin,60000); when placed inside the function showpop(), it is not closing off anything.Plz help.

Comment: Sorry for a little mistake i made. Try `if(r===true)` instead `if(r==true)`. see if this helps ?
also, put setTimeout(closeWin,6000) out of else {} condition or it take 6 secs to close after the user clicks cancel button